# MPMoviePlayerViewController crash on iOS 6.0

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, ios6

I have trouble in my app when it is run in iOS6.0. It works perfectly fine on iOS 5.1.1 and under but on the 6.0 shows `exc_bad_access`.

Please tell me why.

```
-(void)endAniView{

    if (moviePlayer!=nil) {
        [moviePlayer.moviePlayer stop];
        [self removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

This method called when the user touches a button.
What follows are the errors I see on iOS6 but not in previous iOS versions:

```
2012-09-18 16:13:22.410 KiKiSong[992:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-09-18 16:13:22.411 KiKiSong[992:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-09-18 16:13:22.450 KiKiSong[992:907] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem after taping play on a Vimeo video within a UIWebView. Edit: I'm on a iPhone 4S running iOS6

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing it from the super view, try using the following code in its place.

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

This tells the presenting view controller to dismiss the view. It works better than `removeFromSuperview` because if you call this on itself, it will forward the message to the presenting view controller, which seems to be your case.